# Querying for USB devices in Android

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface, usb

I read some parts about Android's USB interfacing, which solves the USB interfacing problems via Java, but I discovered an app, that doesn't interface with USB devices via Java, but (probably) via C++, as it has .so libraries in the APK file, so it uses NDK and JNI.

My question is, is this possible? I haven't been able to find any references to USB in the compiled and decompiled Java files, just in the C++ libraries, albeit very small.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that it is indeed possible to do this, via the `libusbhost.so` library, using it directly, interfacing via JNI.